# How to buy custom fonts to use in a client's project

Tags: web, fonts, visual-web-developer, embedded-fonts

I have always wondering about paying for Font services such as TypeKit to be able to use some of the awesome fonts they offer but I’m also wondering how to manage this fee, I’m talking more for a client’s web site, what do you tell them “you need to continue paying for this service otherwise your site may look different” after a year.

Are font services more for a personal use (use them on your own site)?

Do you use pay font services in clients work? If you do, how do you manage that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typekit has different pricing tiers, the upper levels (starting from $49 currently) allow you to use the fonts on unlimited websites (although not unlimited traffic). You could eat the cost yourself and raise your prices to cover it.

Comment: Is that really what designers/developers do, basically pay for the clients fonts for life?  Thaks